# Watch multiple folders using gulp-watch

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a folder structure like this in my project:

- Common
- Games

  - Game1
  - Game2
  - ...

Each folder contains a list of Typescript files and all games have dependencies to the Common folder.

Compiling everything using Typescript takes about 10 seconds. Would it be possible to create a gulp-watch that watch each game separately?

This is what I have working right now:

```
// Compile
gulp.task('compile-games', ['clean-games'], function () {
var folders = getFolders(inputPaths.games);

var gameTasks = folders.map(function (folder) {
    return gulp.src([
            path.join(inputPaths.common, '/**/*.ts'),
            path.join(inputPaths.games, folder, '/**/*.ts')], { base: inputPaths.scripts })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(typescript({
            target: "ES5",
            noImplicitAny: false,
            sortOutput: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat('Game.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./', { includeContent: true, debug: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(outputPaths.games, folder)));
});

// Watches
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(path.join(inputPaths.games, "**/*.ts"), ["compile-games"]);
    gulp.watch(path.join(inputPaths.common, "**/*.ts"), ["compile-games"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't precisely the solution you're looking for, but it should solve your build time issue:

```
gulp.watch([path.join(inputPaths.games, "**/*.ts"), path.join(inputPaths.common, "**/*.ts")], ['compile-games']);
```

...then install gulp-newer:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-newer
```

...then in your 'compile-games' task, pipe the stream into the gulp-newer plugin directly after gulp.src. Result: only the newly changed files get rebuilt, and the Typescript compiling is done only for these files.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out!

Comment: Let me know if it works, I have some other ideas for you if not :)